# ROR Attaching more than one file in one statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Is there any way to shorten this code for this?? It looks so miserable

```
has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
has_attached_file :image1, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
has_attached_file :image2, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
has_attached_file :image3, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
[:logo, :image1, :image2, :image3].each do |image_symbol| 
   has_attached_file image_symbol, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
          :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"  
end
```

Hope this helps :).